# How to add buttons while program is running

Tags: java, swing, awt

I need to add buttons when the amount of buttons to add is calculated.

I have my button creating code hereish..:

```
private void loadButtons()
{
    if (active_puzzle != null)
    {
        int devider = 5;
        int count = 0;
        JButton puzzleButton[] = new JButton[active_puzzle.getNumberOfPieces()];
        for(int row = 0; row < active_puzzle.getRows(); row++)
        {
            for(int column = 0; column < active_puzzle.getColumns(); column++)
            {
                puzzleButton[count] = new JButton(new ImageIcon( active_puzzle.getPieces()[count].getPieceImage() ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now how to I tell the program that new buttons need to be added to the screen?

Thank you

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.  For tips on dynamically adding components, see the [Nested Layout Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).  It adds labels dynamically on button click.

Comment: Can you provide the full class code? you have to first add them to a JFrame, Panel or something like that and then probably refresh the UI after adding the buttons so they will be displayd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic code for adding a component to a visible GUI is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

then the layout manager can do its job.

Answer (score 0):

Add all of the newly created buttons which you stored in the puzzleButton array to the main JPanel of your program.

Comment: you need to do more than just add the component to the panel.